# StandardOpenOption for directories and files. Files.create..()

Tags: java, io, nio

Why the `StandardOpenOption` parameter is not present at all in the parameter list of this method:
`Files.createDirectory(path, FileAttribute<?>)`?
I am talking about the same StandardOpenOption available for writing a file "Files.write(path,byte[],**options**)" which allows to use the `StandardOpenOption.CREATE` which won't give back any exception if the file already exist.
In `Files.createFile(..)` and `Files.createDirectory()` there is no possibility to insert a StandardOpenOption, so if by mistake I am creating a file which already exist I will get an exception out of it.
Is there any way to insert an option such as `StandardOpenOption.CREATE` in the creation of files and directories using `Files.createFile(...)`,Files.createDirectory(...);

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the behaviour of CREATE you could use:

```
Files.createDirectories
```

If you want to use the options directly you would have to write your own utility method.